Converting gb4e interlinear gloss into a well-formatted docx document
Background
For the purpose of my research, I need to create interlinear linguistic gloss. Initially I used docx document with the conventional glossing through the invisible tables, but the glosses became very messy quickly. So I tried gb4e, and it did created such a beautiful glosses. Therefore, I planned to write my whole document in LaTeX, because after all it is neater than docx anyways.
However, my supervisor did not approve me to write the whole document on LaTeX. It is ruled that the LaTeX format cannot be accepted for submission. The document needs to be in docx format. Knowing Microsoft Word's capability to read pdf documents, I utilized that feature but turns out it did not format the glosses neatly in the Word document.

The converting-gb4e-gloss-into-docx problem
Attempt using gb4e
Interlinear linguistic gloss typically aligns well with each other. Consider this following example using gb4e:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{times}

\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=3cm,
 right=3cm,
 top=3cm,
 bottom=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}


\begin{document}

 \begin{exe}
 
 \let\eachwordone=\it
 
 \noautomath
\setlength{\glossglue}{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}}

\ex % Glosa 1
{\bf(Strategi praanggapan = \textnormal{\textsc{pgp}})}
\glll \?{Геи} \?{всë} \?{равно} \?{пришли} — \?{вопреки} \?{запрету} \\
gei vsë ravno prišli — vopreki zapretu \\
gay semua dengan\textunderscore sama\textsc{.pgp} pergi\textsc{.pgp} — meskipun larangan\textsc{.pgp} \\
\trans “Para kelompok gay, bagaimanapun, tetap pergi, meskipun terdapat larangan” \\

\end{exe}

\end{document}

Which results in this gloss, where all of the words are aligned with each other:

So let us now open the pdf document of the gloss using Microsoft Words.
Attempt opening the pdf file using Microsoft Words
Already after Microsoft Word processed the pdf document, it resulted the glosses to lose its format, where the words are not aligned with each other, and the diacritics are detached from the words. However, the \textsc{} seems to retain its format. Take a look into the Word-read document:

In this case, I will still ended up needing to recreate the invisible tables in Microsoft Words in order to make the interlinear gloss stay aligned to each other.

Goal
My goal now is to be able to convert the gb4e interlinear gloss tex document into docx format where it still retains the original gb4e format, that is, a nicely aligned words and an attached diacritic for each words. Is there any solution for that? I have seen LaTeX to docx converter online, but I am trying to see the solution from LaTeX.

Welcome! Your supervisor won't accept PDF? If not, can you produce the glosses as images and include them that way? (PDF images, maybe.)

No, the document needs to be in docx format. I can just put it as pngs (the glosses), but it would be nicer to turn it into docx text @cfr

You can't get the same TeX output in Word format, if they accept HTML format, then convert your TeX code into HTML format using make4ht
